# NullPointerException while displaying anything in a tab

Tags: android, android-tabs

I am trying to make a tabed interface within the same actvity. 
this is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <AnalogClock android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      />
      <Button android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="A semi-random button"
      />
    </FrameLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

dummy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <RatingBar
          android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

and my activity:

```
public class LActivity extends Activity {


 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);


     TabHost tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
     tabs.setup();

   tabs.addTab(tabs.newTabSpec("tag1").setIndicator("1").setContent(R.id.tab1));
   tabs.addTab(tabs.newTabSpec("tag2").setIndicator("2").setContent(R.id.tab2));
```

the above code works, but if you change `R.id.tab2` to `R.layout.dummy` or `R.id.ratingBar1`, it throws a nullpointerexception.

i intend to display dummy.xml in a tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that `R.id.tab2` works and `R.layout.dummy` doesn't is that `R.id.tab2` is part of the `Activity` content view as it is defined in the layout set to it with `setContentView`.

You can't use a *layout-id* where a *view-id* is expected, and thats why `R.layout.dummy` doesn't work. And you can't expect it to work when using `R.id.ratingBar1` as is not part of the `Activity` content, and how would the activity know where to get that view? Remember you could have several different layouts using an id `ratingBar1`.

What you need to do is place your *dummy* layout within `@android:id/tabcontent`. You can do this with just an `<include>` element. Otherwise, you need to inflate the layout yourself and use the resulting `View` as an argument to `setContent`.

Comment: @arnab321: As I mentioned in the answer, keep your separate layout and use a `<include>` element at the `tabcontent` to get your other layout file referenced. That way your main layout doesn't get cluttered, and you can edit each of your tab pages at each of its separate layouts.